# Permission of CSV-file in PHP

Tags: php

My php file has multiple errors. The first one has to do something with permissions. Normally there's nothing wrong with it it, but now I use a csv-file. I think that's the problem. But I don't understand the other warnings.

Which permission do I have to add?

```
$filename = "menuitems.csv";
$fp = fopen($filename, "r");

while ($data = fgetcsv($fp, filesize($filename), ",")) {
     if (trim($data[0]) == '') break;
     $href = strtolower(substr($data[1], 0, 7));
     if ($href == "http://")
          print "<li> <a href=\"" . data[1] . "\" target=\"_blank\">" . $data[0] . "</a></li>\n";
    else 
         print "<li> <a href=\"" . data[1] . "\" >" . $data[0] . "</a></li>\n";
}

fclose($fp);
echo "</ul>\n";
echo "</div>\n";
```

Warning: fopen(menuitems.csv): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/basis/php/index.php on line 10

Warning: fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/basis/php/index.php on line 11

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/basis/php/index.php on line 21

Comment: The second and third ones are because of the first one. You don't have permission to create a file in that location, and thus the other calls that rely on that file also fail.

Comment: I don't know which permission I have to add, and how?

Answer (score 0):

the csv file that was moved into the document root does not have permissions set correctly. You can do this several ways, including changing permission in the file properties dialog (via right click menu) or use the php command:

```
      chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0644);
```

but installing xampp in its own folder off the root directory instead of Program Files directory will fix this issue in most XAMPP versions.

Comment: I tried this:     chmod ("/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/basis/php/menuitems.csv", 0644); But this didn't work

Comment: then you need to add a \ to the filename. ($filename="\csvfile.csv"); some php versions append this automatically , some dont. I'll Look into the rest of your code here if you have something wrong with your fopen statement.

Comment: What do you exactly mean?

Comment: actually its a web server setting I'm talking about. I've worked with some webservers that I had to state a delimeter in the file name like: <img src="\myimage.jpg">  instead of <img src="myimage.jpg"> could be the same thing going on.